# Выборка данных в определённом диапазоне ADO.NET SQLite

Tags: c#, база-данных, .net, sqlite, ado.net

Использую БД SQLite. Необходимо получить данные из БД за определенный квант времени, что-то вроде BETWEEN (MySQL) по времени. Но есть нюанс, в БД время храниться набором значений: Г.М.Д.Ч.М.С. А не одной строкой.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот запрос:

```
@$SELECT employeeId, year, month, day, hour, minute,
second FROM [employeers] WHERE date >= {startTime} AND date <= {endTime};
```

И сам блок кода:

```
public List<EmployeeDto> SelectEmployeeBetweenTimeStamp(string startTime, string endTime)
    {
        var employeeDto = new List<EmployeeDto>();
        
        using (var connection = new SqliteConnection(connectionString))
        {
            using (var command = new SqliteCommand())
            {
                connection.Open();
                command.Connection = connection;

                command.CommandText = @$SELECT id, employeeId, year, month, day, hour, minute, second, employeeName, employeeLastName FROM
                                    [employeers] WHERE date >= {startTime} AND date <= {endTime};


                command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

                var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    breezeDto.Add(new EmployeeDto
                    {
                        Id = Convert.ToInt32(reader["id"]),
                        EmployeeId = Convert.ToInt32(reader["employeeId"]),
                        Year = Convert.ToInt32(reader["year"]),
                        Month = Convert.ToInt32(reader["month"]),
                        Day = Convert.ToInt32(reader["day"]),
                        Hour = Convert.ToInt32(reader["hour"]),
                        Minutes = Convert.ToInt32(reader["minute"]),
                        Seconds = Convert.ToInt32(reader["second"]),
                        EmployeeName = reader["employeeName"].ToString(),
                        EmployeeLastName = reader["employeeLastName"].ToString()
                    });
                }
            }
        }

        throw new Exception();
    }
```

Входящие параметры это DateTime.ToString() точки начала и конца отсчета.

Как собрать дату из БД в одно целое и сравнить в запросе?

Comment: А зачем в бд оно так хранится? Выглядит, как лёгкий изврат. БД нативно поддерживает хранение даты и времени в одной колонке.

Comment: в SQLite нет типа данных для времени, только строка. Но вы правы на счет структуры столбцов.

Comment: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разделение даты на отдельные столбцы откровенно неудачное решение.

Как выход: в классе `EmployeeDto` добавьте свойство

`public DateTime ResultDate => new DateTime(this.Year, this.Month, ...)`

и после прочтения всех данных из таблицы сможете работать с датами с помощью LINQ используя это свойство.

Если вы только на начальном этапе написания приложения, лучше измените структуру таблицы на хранение даты в одном столбце и тогда с датами можно будет работать сразу в SQL.

Comment: Создать столбец со строковой датой и можно использовать ```public DateTime ResultDate => new DateTime(this.Year, this.Month, ...)``` при добавлении времени в таблицу. Вопрос тогда следующий, сработает ли конструкция -  `WHERE date >= {startTime} AND date <= {endTime};`?

Comment: Что-то вы совсем ничего не поняли. 1) не столбец, а свойство. 2) не SQL, а LINQ для создания выборки по дате.

Comment: Я понял ваш ответ., Но я про то, что бы добавить колонку с нормальной интерпретацией времени.

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант, можно написать такой запрос, приведя в дату и время данные из БД

```
SELECT *, year || '-' || month || '-' || day || ' ' || hour || ':' || minute || ':' || second as DT 
FROM [employeers]
WHERE datetime(DT) BETWEEN datetime('2021-02-10 13:14:19') AND datetime('2021-02-15 13:14:19');
```

И сравнить с входящими параметрами из метода.

```
string startTime.ToString(yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss), string endTime.ToString(yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss)
```

Comment: Тоже вариант, но только это все равно "борьба" с неверной конфигурацией таблицы.

Comment: Согласен, поэтому ввел нормальный формат в одну колонку - '2020-12-30 13:14:19'